# EF 1.0 flattening a left join query

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to execute a linq to entites query in  (Visual Studio  3.5 /EF 1.0) for 3 entities with the following relationships:

xcCRMCounterparty * => 0..1 CSIDsInUse
CSIDsInUse 1 => * xcCIFToCSID

Previously in T SQL I used:

```
select distinct CIF, xcCIFToCSID.xcCSID, CounterpartyName 
from xcCIFToCSID 
left join CSIDsInUse 
on xcCIFToCSID.idCSID = CSIDsInUse.Id
left join xcCRMCounterparty
on CSIDsInUse.Id = xcCRMCounterparty.IdCSID 
order by CounterpartyName
```

Now with EF I'm tried to flatten the result set as below, but I don't know how to flatten the xcCRMCounterparty item i.e. it's a collection rather than a single field

```
 var query = from cifto in entities.xcCIFToCSIDSet.Include(x => x.CSIDsInUse).Include(x => x.CSIDsInUse.xcCRMCounterparty)
                    select new 
                    { 
                        cifto.CIF,
                        cifto.xcCSID,
                        cifto.CSIDsInUse.xcCRMCounterparty
                    };
```

How can I modify my query so that I can generate flattened results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query = from cifto in entities.xcCIFToCSIDSet
            from x in cifto.CSIDsInUse.xcCRMCouterparty
            select new 
                {
                    cifto.CIF,
                    cifto.xcCSID,
                    x.Name
                };
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this generates an inner join. How can I change this to generate a flattened left join?

Comment: If this creates inner join you will most probably have to use SQL directly, stored procedure or upgrade to EFv4 and use its left join support in linq-to-entities.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information. I'll try the stored procedure or sql direct route.